# I have no idea why SDK Manager standalone doesn't work

Tags: android, path, sdk, environment-variables

I want to run SDK manager standalone. I see my SDK manager in Android Studio, but I can't run SDK manager.exe on Windows. I use command `tools\android` and in `cmd`, I see the below message:

```
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat
and tools\bin\avdmanager.bat

Invalid or unsupported command ""

Supported commands are:
android list target
android list avd
android list device
android create avd
android move avd
android delete avd
android list sdk
android update sdk
```

My SDK manger worked before, but now I can't run standalone SDK manger! I googled and tried some solutions, but nothing works. How can I solve this problem?

I think SDK manager is deprecated and I can't use this standalone  without Android Studio. Am I right? :(

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried running SDK by going to the SDK folder? In my case i can browse through it and can run. Here is my path C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\SDK Manager.exe

Comment: Yeah i try but my SDK manager not run !

Comment: Then i think that exe got corrupted. Can you try to uninstall and reinstall Android Studio again and same time update your build tool and all other dependencies to latest one. Quite hectic and time consuming but check this will work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no more standalone GUI edition of the Android SDK Manager, AFAIK. As the message tells you, you can run `sdkmanager.bat` to run [a command-line SDK manager](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Do you mean if i need see my sdk manager, should i try from Android Studio ?

Comment: @Fahim: AFAIK, the only official SDK Manager GUI is the one in Android Studio. So, if you wish to use a GUI, use the SDK Manager in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

The previous standalone SDK Manager is removed from Android latest versions. You can use the Android studio sdk manager. by clicking on the **SDK Manager icon** near the **Run** button.

When SDK Manager is launched, check the **Show Package Details** buttons to view the list of packages